# How to insert a text from an EditText into a database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to get the text from **editText** and input it into my database. The problem I am having is a `NullPointerException` once i try to submit the text. Any help would be appreciated.

ERROR:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

This is from my **MainActivity**:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_add_task:

            final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add New Task")
                    .setMessage("what do you want to do next")
                    .setView(R.layout.custom_view)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            String task;
                            task = text.getText().toString();

                            dbHelper.insertNewTask(task);
                            if(getFragmentRefreshListener()!=null) {
                                getFragmentRefreshListener().onRefresh();
                            }
                            loadTaskList();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();

            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

my **custom_view.xml**:

```
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter a task"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

**my activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lstTask"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/tasks"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: So where is your task code?

Comment: Try declaring editText as a global variable

Comment: The problem lies in your custom view here!

Comment: can you upload the xml layout set in ´MainActivity`?

Comment: I added my activity_main.xml, whats wrong with the custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since I cant see the xml for `MainActivity` layout, here it's what most likely it's causing the NPE.

```
 final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Your searching your edit text in you activity view hierarchy when (assuming from what is shown in the Dialog creation) you should be searching it in the Dialog view hierarchy.

```
      .setView(R.layout.custom_view)
```

There you are setting that view as the view of the dialog and thats probably what is causing the exception. Try fining the reference to the edit text in the onClick method like this:

```
 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Add New Task")
                .setMessage("what do you want to do next")
                .setView(R.layout.custom_view)
                .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        final EditText text = ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        String task;
                        task = text.getText().toString();

                        dbHelper.insertNewTask(task);
                        if(getFragmentRefreshListener()!=null) {
                            getFragmentRefreshListener().onRefresh();
                        }
                        loadTaskList();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                .create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: I tried this but i got the same error:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: when trying to change to this line : final EditText text = ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);  i receive incompatible type error, "Required: android.widget.Edit.text", "Found: android.view.View"

Comment: you must be using outdated versions of android studio cause newer ones doesn't need to cast the view. The answer you posted is what I suggested, thats not very polite but as long as you solved your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what fixed my problem:

I changed this line:

```
final EditText text = ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

To this:

```
final EditText text = (EditText) ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.editText);
```